# How to turn off Android corner page curl?

Tags: android-device-manager, swype

I'm having an Android page curl issue. 
I've read up on it and a lot of people say it's a clean master app.. but I don't have that app, or omniswipe.. or and of the other apps mentioned... My phone died earlier today, and when I turned it on the curl was suddenly there... Idk where it came from or how to get rid of it. Because it's sapping my battery, I can see the difference, and it frankly really annoying. Ive even had to move all my app up to the top of the pages just so I don't inadvertently swipe the tiniest bit and that curl pops up.... 
Please help. [image][image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I finally figured it out. It was in my Antivirus Free app. The app that came already installed on my phone. Lazy swipe was a feature added in the settings. 
Just turn it off~
I at least hope that this helps someone else~